# Unresolved includes in eclipse CDT where path name is not exact

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm including a file from another project, but I have a problem because of a subtle difference in the include path.

```
#include "foo/Foo.h"
```

Will not find the file I'm looking for because the file is actually in the directory "foo/src/Foo.h"

I've played around with the paths and symbols references tab in the project settings, but haven't found a way to get the "src" part to be appended to what I search for.  I can get around this by having a reference to my output directory, but then I would obviously be opening a copy of the header instead of the original.  Any ideas or am I SOL?

Comment: Symlinks come to mind, but why is that inclusion there -- how could it possibly be useful?

Answer (score 0):

I can see why what you are trying to do would be useful. However, I'd council against even trying. You are circumventing a C convention, not an Eclipse convention. You are likely to end up paying for that later, even if you could get it to work (using symbolic links or another filesystem indirection mechanism).

How about one of these two options? I'd say the best way to do it is to `#include "foo/src/Foo.h"`.

If you don't have name conflicts, then you can just `#include "foo.h"` and add `someplace/foo/src` to your include paths, which would be the most standard way of doing things.